# What is the meaning of double curly braces initializing a C-struct?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm currently working with legacy *C++* code, successfully compiled with gcc 2.9.X.
I've been asked to port this legacy code to gcc 3.4.X. Most of the errors were easily corrected, but this particular one puzzles me.

The context :

```
 struct TMessage 
   {
    THeader header;
    TData data;
   };

 struct THeader
   {
    TEnum myEnum;
    TBool validity;
   };
```

What was done :

```
 const TMessage init = {{0}};

 /* Later in the code ... */
 TMessage message = init;
```

**My question(s)** :
What is the meaning of the {{}} operator ?  Does it initialize the first field (the *header*) to a binary 0 ? Does it initialize the first field of the first structure (the *enum*) to (literal) 0 ?

The 3.4.6 error I get is `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'TEnum'`, either with one or two pairs of curly brackets.

How can I set my structure to a bunch of 0's without using memset ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you porting your code from an old version of gcc to another old version of gcc?

Comment: To compile/link/execute it on another platform.

Comment: Don't know about C++. In C there is no error (perhaps your compiler is being over helpful to the point of being wrong)

Comment: And you really should not attempt to write multi-language source files. It's much more effort than it's worth. Choose a language (C or C++ ... or D or Eiffel or Forth or ...) and stick with it.

Comment: As I said, it's legacy code, I don't have the right to change anything except what does not compile in 3.4.6. Otherwise I would agree with you ;)

Comment: SunOS 3.4 C (not a C++) definitely supports {{ }} initializer syntax in 1987. It's likely that it did as far back as 1985 or so too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It initialises all fields of the POD structure to 0.

Rationale:

```
const SomeStruct init = {Value};
```

Initialises the first field of SomeStruct to Value, the rest of the structure to zero (I forget the section in the standard, but it's there somewhere)

Thus:

```
const SomeOtherStruct init = {{Value}};
```

Initialises the first field of the first field of the structure (where the first field of the structure is itself a POD struct) to Value, and the rest of the first field to zero, and the rest of the structure to 0.

Additionally, this only isn't working because c++ forbids implicit conversion of `int` to enum types, so you could do:

```
const SomeOtherStruct init = {{TEnum(0)}};
```

Comment: So you're saying `const TMessage init = {{myEnumFirstValue}};` would initialize my enum, then every other field to 0 ? It compiles successfully, I'm concerned about runtime now. thanks anyway !

Comment: The relevant section of the standard is 8.5.1.7: *If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be value-initialized.*

Comment: What does the last part mean ? _shall be value-initialized_ : by the compiler ?

Comment: As far as I know value-initialized will always mean default-constructed in this context, which means set to 0 for simple types. (I'm pretty sure everything else ends up as zero...)

Comment: Going a little further, there is another `struct` which has a boolean as its first field. Of what use is the `{{0}}` then ? Is it an error ? (it would not be the first :p). // EDIT: Thanks @Auto

Comment: int converts implicitly to bool (and, unfortunately, vice-versa), so using a plain zero should be fine

Comment: @Autopulated: If no default-constructor is present, all non-static members (also for base-classes) are value-initialized (it basically works recursively). For primitive types, value-initialization means zero-initialization (this is the termination of the recursion).

Answer (score 3):

- The first braces is for `struct TMessage`
- The second brace is for `struct THeader`
- The zero literal is for `TEnum myEnum`

In this case you are initializing `TEnum` with `int` `0`, which is `incompatible conversion`.

So you must add casting like this:

```
const TMessage init = {{TEnum(0)}};
```

In C/C++, if you `partially initialized` structure or array (only some of the first fields/elements), the rest will be initialized by the `default constructor` (which is zero-initialization for primitive types). **Compile error will occur if there is no default constructor or if the constructor is declared as `private`.**

Comment: It is not correct that the rest will always be initialized to zero. As I posted in a comment to @Autopulated's answer, they will be *value-initialized*. For instance, if one the members is of a class-type with a default-constructor, then that constructor will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can hink of it as a multi dimensional array (if that helps). You then reset two dimensions to 0 with that command. This works since (I assume) that the values within the struct can take 0 as a value.

Comment: Thanks ! I was missing the fact that every **other** field was initialized to 0, though.