# Difference between { 0 } & { { 0 } } for a structure

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of double curly braces initializing a C-struct ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251160/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-curly-braces-initializing-a-c-struct)

for this following structure,

```
typedef struct matrix
{
    float data[16];
} matrix;
```

Is there any difference between,

```
matrix test1 = {0};
```

and

```
matrix test1 = { { 0 } };
```

when it comes to initializing the **data** member of the structure. Both initializes **data**  to zero.

Some insight when it comes to C or C++, would be great.

Comment: There is no partial initialization in C. An object either isn't initialized at all, or it is fully initialized. `{0}` explicitly initializes the first member to 0 and implicitly initializes (to 0) all other members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `matrix test1 = { 0 }` you will initialize test1 with all zero's and with `matrix test1 = { { 0 } }` You will initialize test1.data. with all zero's in this case it does the same actually since you don't have any other data definitions in your struct :)

Comment: That means, if I had another member in the struct then, using { { 0 } } wouldn't initialize the second variable as zero? But, that doesn't happen, however I use single or double, all are being initialized with zero!