# What is this double curly brace in C, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

In reference to [this source code](https://github.com/rentzsch/JREnum/blob/semver-1.x/JREnumTest/JREnumTest/main.m) what is the purpose of the double curly braces within the `@autoreleasepool`?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        {{
            assert([EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesByLabel() count] == 1);
            assert([[EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesByLabel() objectForKey:@"EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);

            assert([EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesByValue() count] == 1);
            assert([[EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesByValue() objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] isEqual:@"EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1"]);

            EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues a = 0;

            assert(EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1 == a);
            assert([@"EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1" isEqualToString:EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesToString(a)]);
            assert(EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesFromString(EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesToString(EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1), &a));
            assert(EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues_Constant1 == a);

            a++;
            assert([@"<unknown EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValues: 1>" isEqualToString:EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesToString(a)]);
            assert(!EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesFromString(@"foo", &a));
        }}
        {{
            assert([EnumWith1ConstantSansExplicitValuesTrailingCommaByLabel() count] == 1);
        }}
    ...
    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be this could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251160/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-curly-braces-initializing-a-c-struct

Comment: @User42 no, this isn't declaring a struct.

Comment: Answer this question: What does a curly brace mean? Then answer this question: What does a curly brace inside a curly brace mean? It's an obvious consequence of the first answer. The @autoreleasepool has nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: It's not technically incorrect, theoretically you cut put how many curly braces you want, provided that you close them.

Comment: You should ask the author. I am nearly certain that there is no special significance to these, i.e. he's probably using them because he can. One possibility is to use these to mark his test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about the double-curly-braces*. It's just used by the authors to logically separate sections of code within a rather long method.

*: Beyond the single-curly-brace behavior of declaring a scope block.