# Why do I need more curly braces when initializing this structure?

Tags: c, struct

At first I tried to initialize a structure like this:

```
struct {
    char age[2];        // Hold two 1-Byte ages
} studage[] = {
    {23, 56},
    {44, 26}
};
```

But that gives me a compiler warning about missing braces, so I used more braces as suggested by the compiler and ended up with this:

```
struct {
    char age[2];        // Hold two 1-Byte ages
} studage[] = {
    {{23, 56}},
    {{44, 26}}
};
```

No warning. Why do I need the extra braces?

Comment: Isn't the outer one for structure and the inner one for char array that is inside it?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. The compiler isn't "demanding" anything.

Comment: duplicate of [What is the meaning of double curly braces initializing a C-struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251160/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-curly-braces-initializing-a-c-struct) ?

Comment: Not relevant yet, and possibly only if you are dealing with the ages of old things, but in C, `char` could be `signed` or `unsigned` depending on your platform. Safer to use `unsigned char` (unless you're dealing with negative energy antiparticles which can have negative ages according to some physical models.)

Comment: §6.7.9/30 says "Note that the fully bracketed and minimally bracketed forms of initialization are, in general, less likely to
cause confusion."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an array of structs, the struct has one member which is an array.

```
struct {
    char age[2];        // Hold two 1-Byte ages
} studage[] = {
              ^ 
         This is for the studage array
    { { 23, 56}},
    ^ ^ 
    | this is for the age array
  this is for the anonymous struct

    {{44, 26}}
};
```

Perhaps it's easier to see if your struct had another member:

```
struct {
        int id;
        char age[2];
    } studage[] = {
        {1, {23, 56}},
         ^   ^    ^
         id  |    | 
           age[0] |
                 age[1]
     };
```