# Modify all elements of an array at the same time

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way to modify all elements of an array at the same time?
I mean a for loop just loops through the array and does everything one by one.

NOTE:
This is .gsc/.csc (which is kind of its own programming language), but it follows a basic C syntax:

```
function setCOD7DecodeFx()
{
    alphabet = strTok("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z", " ");
    test = "text";
    is_done = false;

    //I want all of the letters of text to change at the same time
    while(!is_done)
    {
        //I want this to happen without having to do text[num]
        test[0] = alphabet[rand(0, alphabet.size - 1)];
        test[1] = alphabet[rand(0, alphabet.size - 1)]; //rand -> rand(min, max)
        test[2] = alphabet[rand(0, alphabet.size - 1)]; //alphabet.size -> counts all elements in an array
        test[3] = alphabet[rand(0, alphabet.size - 1)];
        wait 0.25;
    }
    wait 3;
    is_done = true;
    test = "text";
}
```

Would it work with a foreach statement? I know 'foreach' doesn't exist in C, but it exists in gsc.

```
foreach(element in array)
```

Comment: It should be pretty self explanatory. I hope I made it as clear as possible.

Comment: *"I mean a for loop just loops through the array and does everything one by one."* Yes, that is correct. Some languages that have builtin methods that appear to operate on all array entries at once, but behind the scenes they're still just updating one at a time. C doesn't bother to try to hide the details from you.

Comment: Given enough cores you can parallelize it with e.g.: OpenMP (or manually) but the overhead will be gigantic for those four bytes. Also:  `rand` is not threadsafe, so you might get four equal values. Or not. It depends.

Comment: The closest you can get to _apparent_ simultaneous assignment using C, (assuming a single line of execution) would be during initialization.  eg: `char array[3] = {{0}};` _[example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6251190/645128)_, or using a function such as `memset()`.  But as the other comment states, even though they appear simultaneous, the memory locations are being modified one at a time.

Comment: Would it work with a foreach statement maybe?

Comment: *"[The language C does not have collections or a `foreach` construct.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#C)"*

Comment: Comment to down voters.  Question posed here is from a programmer who is apparently delving into C.  It appears to be a sincere, well formed question complete with formatted code to illustrate question, and is actually interesting if you give it a chance.  _I can see no real need for down vote._  If there is something that OP should do differently, put it into a comment.

Comment: @user3386109 As I said it's not really C. It's gsc or csc, Both are based on C and follow the basic C syntax. In gsc/csc there is a foreach statement.

Comment: @Datboi That's probably worth explaining in more detail in the question itself. The tag wiki for `csc` says that it's C#, not C.

Comment: @user3386109 This csc has nothing to do with the csc you mentioned. Both gsc and csc are practically the same, the only difference is that gsc runs on the server-side and csc on the client-side. I can't really explain it. It's weird I know...

Answer (score 0):

To modify a *small* array like `test` (no more than sizeof `int` characters) code could use the following which has many limitations (endian, `int` size, etc.).

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const unsigned base_letter = 'a';
    const unsigned offset_pow2 = 5;  // a-z and "{|}~" and code 127

    const unsigned char_mask = (1u << offset_pow2) - 1;
    unsigned mask = 
        char_mask << 24 | char_mask << 16 | char_mask << 8 | char_mask;
    unsigned offset = 
        base_letter << 24 | base_letter << 16 | base_letter << 8 | base_letter;
    union {
      char test[5];
      unsigned r;
    } u = { "text" };
    u.r = (rand() & mask) + offset;  // Set all characters at once
    printf("<%s>\n", u.test);
}
```

Output

```
<nury>
```