# Double curly braces in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, syntax, symengine

What do the double curly braces in the following line of C++ code mean?

```
piranha::symbol_set ss({{piranha::symbol(detail::poly_print(var))}});
```

For context, this is from a file in the SymEngine code (`"symengine/polys/uintpoly_piranha.h"`), which can be found at the link below, as can the Piranha library which is used in the above line.

- SymEngine source code: https://github.com/symengine/symengine
- Piranha source code: https://github.com/bluescarni/piranha

I know single curly braces are used as  initializer lists, but the meaning of the double curly braces within the set of parentheses makes little sense to me.

The main thing I found on double curly braces was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251160/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-curly-braces-initializing-a-c-struct), but it does not seem applicable here.

Also, I apologize for linking source code like this but I am unsure of how to make a smaller example given my lack of understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Curly braces can be used to describe

- an initializer list, which explains the outer braces (creating an `std::initializer_list` of symbols, see [the corresponding constructor](https://github.com/bluescarni/piranha/blob/843bfc1147b6c47258bdd5b9ffb966a597a960f3/include/piranha/symbol_set.hpp#L266))
- a shorthand notation to a constructor call, which explains the inner
  braces (creating an instance of `symbol` using the move constructor, see [the corresponding constructor](https://github.com/bluescarni/piranha/blob/843bfc1147b6c47258bdd5b9ffb966a597a960f3/include/piranha/symbol.hpp#L97))
  If the type of a parameter is known beforehand, instead of `symbol{parameters}` you can just write `{parameters}`. This also works for return values and variable initialization.

So what actually happens in this line is:

- a `std::string` is returned from `detail::poly_print(var)`
- This string is used to construct a `piranha::symbol`
- This temporary value is then passed to the move constructor (I'm guessing here) of `symbol`, constructing another `symbol`
  *This seems a bit redundant, but I haven't tried if the code works with only one pair of braces*
- This `piranha::symbol` is then stored in a `std::initializer_list`
- which is then passed to the constructor of `piranha::symbol_set`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer to my somewhat non-minimal question. How come the inner curly braces are outside of `symbol` though? The usage I am familiar with for your second bullet is something like `symbol s{"x"};`.

Comment: Ah, I skimmed over your code too quickly. The answer is actually more complex, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the third bullet in the second half of your answer. Is the syntax that accomplishes that third bullet `{symbol_object}`? And, given a symbol was just constructed, why construct the same symbol again?

Comment: Ah your edit to the earlier bullet clarifies the first question.

Comment: This seems to be redundant, but I haven't tried if it works without the inner braces (OR without piranha::symbol(...))